# Through 3 dices undistinguishable. Probability that the result has three different result

Tags: probability

We through 3 not distinguishable dices.

1) What is the probability that 2 dices has same number and the other one a different number ?

2) What is the probability that the three dices has different number.

---

**Attempt**

1) I did in two different way. First I say that the first dice has $6$ possibility, the second one, only one possibility and the last one, 5 possibilities. Since there is no order, we multiply by $3!$. At the end, we get $6\cdot 5\cdot 3!$

2) First dice has 3 possibilities, second dice two possibilities and the last one 4 possibilities. Since there is no order, we get $6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3!$.

---

I try to do in a different way, I see the problem  i.e. I take as sample space $$\{\{i,j,k\}\mid i\in \{R_1,...,R_6\}, j\in\{G_1,...,G_6\}, k\in \{B_1,...,B_6\} \},$$

where $R_i$ is a red ball with the number $i$, $B_i$ is the blue ball with a number $i$ and $G_i$ is a green ball with the number $i$.

1) To have 3 ball of different color with 2 ball with the same number and one with an other number, I take $\binom{6}{2}$ number. Then I take $\binom{2}{1}$ number and $\binom{3}{2}$ ball. I only have 1 choice for the last ball. To finish, I get $$\binom{6}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}=6\cdot 5\cdot 3,$$
which is twice less than previous.

2) Same, I take $\binom{6}{3}$ color. Then $\binom{3}{2}$ number and $\binom{3}{2}$ color. Then $\binom{2}{1}$ ball in a color and all other ball are determinated. Finally, I get
$$\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}=6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3$$
which is also twice less than previous. So why doing like that is wrong ? I don't really see where I loose cases.

Comment: what are the answers provided to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 1 number that is part of a pair, and one number that is not.

And 3 possible orderings.  (xxy, xyx, yxx)

And $6^3$ ways to roll 3 dice.

$\frac {6\cdot 5\cdot 3}{6^3} = \frac {15}{36}$

alternatively we could say that there are

$6\cdot 5 \cdot 4$ ways to roll 3 dice such that none match.

and 6 ways such that all 3 match.

$1 - \frac {6\cdot 4\cdot 3 + 6}{6^3} = 1 - \frac {21}{36} = \frac {15}{36}$

Comment: "There is $6\cdot 5\cdot 4$ way to roll three dice that none match." This is correct if you can distinguish them. If you cannot it's $6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3!$, because for example all permutation of $(1,2,3)$ will give the same shot.

Comment: $6\cdot 5\cdot 4 \cdot 3! > 6^3$ which should be a give away that there is something wrong with that calculation.

Comment: I don't get the point. Do you agree for example that the probability to have the result 1,2,3 is $\frac{6}{6^3}=\frac{1}{6^2}$ ? Because $(1,2,3)$ occur with probability $1/6^3$ and all permutation of $(1,2,3)$ will give the result $\{1,2,3\}$. Do you agree with this ?

Comment: If you say that the number of ways to roll 3 dice such that they are all different is greater than the number of ways to roll 3 dice, then you have a problem.  

As for you second question, counting the number of ways to roll 3 dice such that they are all different as $6\cdot 5 \cdot 4$ counts the possibility of getting (3,2,1),(2,3,1), (1,2,3), etc. as separate events.

Comment: You can divide numerator and denominator by $3!$ but it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: @Doug M,$\frac{21}{36}=\frac{126}{216}$

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question (2) is $\frac{\binom{8}{5}}{6^3}=0.259259$, if you consider the results(123,132,231,213,321,312) as same and not different. If you consider these results as different, then the probability is $\frac{120}{216}$

Answer to your question(1) is already given by Doug M